# Tracking a user's activity on a WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

I'm a little confused on how I should be tracking user engagement on a website. Specifically one that is made with WordPress.

So far I've looked into Google analytics and that seems to be a viable option. But I haven't found a clear answer to if I am able to track the activity of a specific user.

The goal is to be able to reward users for spending time on the site and interacting with it. All current users have account.

Is it possible to track a specific user's activity on a site using Google analytics?

Also, it seems that there may be a way to do this manually without google analytics. However I do not have much experience with building websites.I suspect it involves a lot of PHP which I am unfamiliar with.

Thank you!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We're not general WP/Google tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first place you should look is https://wordpress.org/plugins/ There are plugins for Google Analytics, stats, tracking, etc.